# KSH tab completion - I get literal tab if no matches?

Tags: ksh, autocomplete

Welcome to the 3rd in my ongoing series of questions about KSH :).

As always I'm dealing with :

```
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
```

and switching to Bash or Tcsh is not an option.

Tab completion:  it mostly works in a way that's similar enough to Tcsh to make me happy.  But, if there are no matches, instead of doing nothing and beeping, KSH inserts a **literal tab**.  Why would I want that?  More importantly, how can I change that behavior?

Comment: FWIW, this is also the behaviour of the `dash` and `csh` shells. Different shells do things differently.

Comment: Interesting.  From what I had read in either the O'reilly KSH book or random websites, I was expecting a beep with no further response, instead of the literal tab....which had me hoping there was a secret option to enable that.